# How to connect Spark EMR cluster with AWS elasticsearch cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I have one spark streaming job which is running on aws environment say spark cluster A. I have also provisioned another new aws elasticsearch cluster say ES cluster B.
Now i have to send data from spark i.e. cluster A to Elastic search cluster i.e. cluster B  for which i am taking reference from 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html

based on above link guideline 
for cluster A in the spark conf i have set below parameters

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ElasticSearchTest");

    conf.set("spark.serializer", org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.class.getName()); 
    conf.set("es.nodes", [endpoint of aws elasticsearch cluster]);
    conf.set("es.port", "9200");
```

I am allowing all within the access policy during setup of aws elastic cluster.

i am getting below exception. it shows classnotfound. however this is not the right issue also i have verified that class is present in the POM file(maven)

[image]
I am new to work with aws elasticsearch in integration with spark could somebody please guide me necessary configuration as what is needed to achieve it?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to connect spark to an aws elasticsearch cluster and there's a serious dearth of useful documentation, along with an overwhelming number of useless google results.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use some connector to read from elastic search, and convert it into an RDD for manipulation, here is an example of a connector which i think would work (but not tested)

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop#apache-spark

Comment: Thanks for your time. Well i am looking how to connect and put data from spark streaming which is running on cluster A to one different aws elasticsearch cluster. I am using org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark to store rdd into elastic search.  the question i have is to understand which API are there  which can be used as java service in integration with spark to ingest streaming data to aws elasticsearch.

Comment: like for an example if we want to use spark to SNS then we use AmazonSNSClient and send data similar ground i am looking what i should use for elasticsearch for aws.